# Подстановка переменой при обращении к другой переменной, php

Tags: php, время

Подскажите, можно ли в последней строчке сделать так, чтобы название переменной-массива, откуда подставляется значение (`first_str_night`, `first_str_morning`, `first_str_day`, `first_str_evening`) выбиралось автоматически из переменной `$now`? Без if-ов. То есть что-то вроде `$first_str_.$now.` Нельзя?

```
    // Вычисление времени суток
    ini_set('date.timezone', $timezone);
    $hour_now = intval(date('H', time())); 
    if (($hour_now >= 0) && ($hour_now < 7)) { $now = 'night' };
    if (($hour_now >= 7) && ($hour_now < 12)) { $now = 'morning' };
    if (($hour_now >= 12) && ($hour_now < 18)) { $now = 'day' };
    if (($hour_now >= 18) && ($hour_now <= 23)) { $now = 'evening' };

    // Строки, соответствующему дню суток.
    $first_str_night = array("Здравствуйте","Доброй ночи");
    $first_str_morning = array("Здравствуйте","Доброе утро","Доброго утра","Утро доброе");
    $first_str_day = array("Здравствуйте","Добрый день","Доброго дня","День добрый");
    $first_str_evening = array("Здравствуйте","Добрый вечер","Доброго вечера","Вечер добрый");

    $ch_first_str = 1;
    $first_string = $first_str_evening[$ch_first_str] ."!\n";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$messages = array(
    'night' =>  array("Здравствуйте","Доброй ночи"),
    'morning' => array("Здравствуйте","Доброе утро","Доброго утра","Утро доброе"),
    'day' => array("Здравствуйте","Добрый день","Доброго дня","День добрый"),
    'evening' => array("Здравствуйте","Добрый вечер","Доброго вечера","Вечер добрый")
);

function getMessage($key, array $messages) {
    $hour_now = intval(date('H', time()));
    if ($hour_now >= 0 && $hour_now < 7) { 
        $now = 'night';
    } elseif ($hour_now >= 7 && $hour_now < 12) {
        $now = 'morning';
    } elseif ($hour_now >= 12 && $hour_now < 18) {
        $now = 'day';
    } else {
        $now = 'evening';
    }
    if (isset($messages[$now][$key])) {
        return $messages[$now][$key];
    }
    return null;
}

echo getMessage(1, $messages);
```

Смотрите [результат](http://ideone.com/ubpjb4).

> То есть что-то вроде $first_str_.$now.

Подобные подставки следует избегать, хотя это и возможно. Один из случаев, когда это допустимо - при использовании [магических методов](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.magic.php). Но лучше не увлекаться - без фанатизма.